# Inject dependency in the ConfigureServices

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

In my ASP.Net Core application I need to inject some dependencies (a repository, in my case) in the `ConfigureServices` method.

The problem is that method does not allow the use of multiple arguments to inject dependencies. What to do instead ?

Here is my code

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOptions();

    // ... 
    services.AddSingleton<ITableRepositories, TableClientOperationsService>();

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        // options.ClientId = ...
        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnTicketReceived = async context =>
            {
                var user = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity;
                if (user.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    // ... 
                    // vvv 
                    // HERE, I need the ITableRepositories repository; 
                    // vvv
                    var myUser = await repository.GetAsync<Connection>(userId);
                    // ... 
                }
                return;
            }
        };
    });
}
```

How can I inject the dependency here?

**EDIT:**

Following the Chris idea (bellow), that seem to work:

```
public class Startup
{
    // private repository, used in ConfigureServices, initialized in Startup
    ITableRepositories repository;

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        // ... etc etc
        Configuration = builder.Build();

        // init repository here
        this.repository = new TableClientOperationsService();
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can access the service container via the `HttpContext.RequestServices` of the current context.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddOptions();

    // ... 
    services.AddSingleton<ITableRepositories, TableClientOperationsService>();

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddOpenIdConnect(options => {
        // options.ClientId = ...
        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents {
            OnTicketReceived = async context => {
                var user = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity;
                if (user.IsAuthenticated) {
                    // ... 

                    // get the ITableRepositories repository
                    var repository = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ITableRepositories>();
                    var myUser = await repository.GetAsync<Connection>(userId);

                    // ... 
                }
                return;
            }
        };
    });
}
```

So technically you don't need access to the dependency within the `ConfigureServices` as the inline expression could be extracted into its own function.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddOptions();

    // ... 
    services.AddSingleton<ITableRepositories, TableClientOperationsService>();

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddOpenIdConnect(options => {
        // options.ClientId = ...
        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents {
            OnTicketReceived = TicketReceived
        };
    });
}

private async Task TicketReceived(TicketReceivedContext context) {
    var user = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity;
    if (user.IsAuthenticated) {
        // ... 

        // get the ITableRepositories repository
        var repository = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ITableRepositories>();
        var myUser = await repository.GetAsync<Connection>(userId);

        // ... 
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't. However, you can utilize the `StartUp` constructor to set one or more properties that you can utilize inside `ConfigureServices`. For example:

```
public StartUp(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...

    FooInstance = new Foo();
}

public IFoo FooInstance { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // you can now use `Foo` here, without injecting it.
}
```

**EDIT (based on code added to question)**

In this particular scenario, especially since this is a singleton, you can simply create an instance manually and then bind to that instance instead of a generic type. For example:

```
var repository = new TableClientOperationsService();
services.AddSingleton<ITableRepositories>(repository);
```

Then, you can simply utilize this variable directly in the code below where you need it:

```
var myUser = await repository.GetAsync<Connection>(userId);
```

Comment: Do you mean, I can use say, `public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, ITableRepositories repository)`?

Comment: I tried, but it says in runtime : 'Unable to resolve service for type 'MyApp.Data.ITableRepositories' while attempting to activate 'MyApp.Startup'.'

Comment: Sorry. I guess `IHostingEnvironment` was a bad example, as `StartUp` actually takes that as a param. I didn't mean to imply that you can inject things here instead. I meant that you can literally create instances of what you need and then allow those to be available to `ConfigureServices` and/or `Configure`. The only thing you can custom inject into is `Configure`. Anything else that's not already passed into the constructor or `ConfigureServices` must be created inside to be used in those methods.

Comment: what do you mean by `Foo = new Foo();` did you mean `Foo myFoo = new Foo();`?

Comment: No, but I could see how that's confusing. The first `Foo` is actually the property on the class, whereas the second `Foo` is the actually class you're creating an instance of. The compiler is smart enough to understand based on context, but it's admittedly not very readable. I'll update.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Since I have no idea if this is a good idea or not, this is more of a question than a suggestion, but what about calling services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<ITableRepositories>()?

Comment: That's probably a valid option as well, but more in the scenario where you're dealing with a transient service. Since this one is singleton-scoped, it's more direct to just bind it to an instance and use that instance directly.

Comment: I already added `services.AddSingleton<ITableRepositories, TableClientOperationsService>();` does it not duplicate the same code?

Comment: Put the code I have in place of that. You're going to bind to the variable instead of the generic type.

Comment: @MattM: Building the provider just to resolve a service and throw it away? Then you end up with two DbContext instances or all resolved services

Comment: @Tseng That makes sense. Like I said, it was more of a question. Thanks for the clarification.